# How can I append something to input based on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a dropdown (Which says, URL or SSH).

Whenever the user enters something for example: `192.168.2.1`

If **URL** is selected, I wanted to append **http://** and when **SSH** is selected, **ssh:/**/ should be "appended" to the IP address.

**My code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name-in" class="col-md-3 label-heading">
        <select name="urloption" style="width: 100px;">
            <option value="URL">URL</option>
            <option value="URL">SSH</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name-in" name="urldata" value="" placeholder="Enter your Lab info">
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Attempt:**

I have created a  class and based on click, can I do this?

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $(".dynamic").html(this.value);
});
```

How can I do this with HTML?

Comment: Ok. Adding my attempt.

Comment: I'm totally new to Jquery. I have attempted to do this but I'm facing issues. I just want to append "http://" and "ssh://" before the ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is capture an event on both input elements, and then change the text based on each selection and event.

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $(".dynamic").html($('select').val().toLowerCase() +'://' + this.value);
});
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $(".dynamic").html(this.value.toLowerCase() +'://'+ $('input').val());
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok49wcvd/)

Comment: But I have one issue, with this one. If I enter something and leave it blank, (Erase) I still see http:// or ssh:// instead of blank. How can i fix that?

Comment: Is there any alternative for keyup? Because it detects the keys which are typed before this dropdown's as well.

Comment: @DarkKnight [Here's the updated jsFiddle with your requests](http://jsfiddle.net/wdcmyz93/). For the 2nd question...I've just used a specific identifier for the input element.